# Why is OperationContext.Current null in IAuthorizationPolicy.Evaluate() but only the first two times?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, network-programming

I have implemented a WCF service with some custom authentication and authorisation.

The Evaluate method of my class which implements IAuthorizationPolicy is being called 3 times.

This is occurring because, within the Evaluate method, I am attempting to access the client IP address from the OperationContext.Current property as follows:

```
OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
MessageProperties prop = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpoint = prop[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;

IPAddress address = null;
if (endpoint != default(RemoteEndpointMessageProperty))
{
    IPAddress.TryParse(endpoint.Address, out address);
}
return address;
```

The OperationContext.Current property is always null the first two times the method is run, but by the third time the Evaluate method is called the property has been set.

At what stage is the OperationContext.Current property being set? and from where?

Is there anything I can do about this? It isn't causing any massive problems - the authorisation goes through on the third pass through the method... but it just feels like this isn't correct to me.

If anyone can fill me in on something I'm doing wrong, or neglecting to do that would be great. Or, just an explanation as to why I'm seeing this behaviour would also be really interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your case is really interesting, I may spend some time on investigating it.

I think you can try to develop a custom ServiceAuthorizationManager, and in the CheckAccessCore method, you should always have access to OperationContext.Current.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that until all authorization is done, WCF does not even set up an operation context.  They authenticate/authorize first and then, only when successful, embarks on invoking your operation by creating a context and then invoking it.

So, sadly, you're just out of position.

However, I, too, am interested in getting the IP at this point.